# How to create a file by registerMultiTask (gruntjs)

Tags: gruntjs

I want gruntjs to create a file on each build that contains some PHP code to define a version number.

the following code fragments are in my grunt.initConfig:

1st some meta

```
meta: {
  versionfile: '<?php \n' +
    'define(\'VERSION\', \'<%= grunt.template.today("yyyymmddhhii") =%>\'); \n' +
    '?>'
}
```

2nd the configuration

```
versionfile: {
  'lib/define-version.php': '<%= meta.versionfile %>'
}
```

and then the multitask definition

```
grunt.registerMultiTask('versionfile', 'create version file.', function() {
    grunt.file.write(this.target, this.data);
});
```

when I run the job the following error comes up and the file is not written:

```
Running "versionfile:lib/define-version.php" (versionfile) task
Warning: An error occurred while processing a template (Unexpected token )). Use --force to continue.
```

I am thankful for every hint on what exactly this error means.

Maybe there is another way to write a file containing the php-code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. The correct configuration has a = too much.

Instead of

```
'define(\'VERSION\', \'<%= grunt.template.today("yyyymmddhhii") =%>\'); \n' +
```

it must be

```
'define(\'VERSION\', \'<%= grunt.template.today("yyyymmddhhMM") %>\'); \n' +
```

(ignore the ii>MM, that's just another error ;)